# Getting Blender to export .ply files with vertex colors

Tags: materials, export, file-format, vertex-colors

I'm trying to get Blender to export .ply files with vertex colors and triangular faces.

First, I assign my model a material, and change its diffuse color. Then, in edit mode, with my whole model selected, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to triangulate the faces. Then, I go to *Export > Stanford (.ply)*, and making sure include vertex colors is selected, I export it.

However, when I look at the file, it has no color data, and the faces are not triangles (The faces consist of a seemingly random number of indices each).

Am I doing anything wrong? I've tried searching quite a bit but can't seem to find anything. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things here:

The diffuse color you assigned isn't part of the Vertex Color content, they are distinct from eachother. If you want to give a single colour to all faces, then go to Vertex Paint mode and masking mode, select all faces, then pick a colour from the colour-wheel and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> . That will set the vertex colour for all faces. and Save.

[image]

For triangulation, you might have to make a duplicate of your model and triangulate, then press save, then export. Else I think the exporter will export the mesh's data from the most recent saved state (that wasn't triangulated yet).

Comment: Thank you. I got the color working just fine now, but i still can't get it to export triangular faces, even when I triangulate it, save it, close it, open and then export it.

Comment: you can test the geometry generated by blenders .ply exporter by reimporting it (File->Import .ply ) . To me it looks like it triangulates just fine, perhaps your importer program is auto "quading" ? What version of Blender? if not 2.74, get it anyway.

Comment: you can open the .ply file in a text editor to see exactly what kind of data it contains.  some lines are   x, y, z, r, g, b and others are the indices..(line is prefixed with the number of vertices to follow) ..

Comment: Ok, it was working fine. Was just reading the file wrong. Thank you vary much, you saved me quite a lot of work.

Comment: @zeffii I just tried using dynamic paint to transfer to vertex color from texture, but when I exported to .ply, all the RBG colors are (255,255,255).

Comment: @JuneWang ask a new question on the main page.