# Vertex coloring on textured models to use in Unity?

Tags: texturing, export, unity, vertex-colors

I am making a Nintendo 64/ PS1 inspired game in Unity. I know that those consoles did not have lighting and instead used **vertex colors on textured models** to add variations in light and in color to save on space. Like Banjo-Kazooie, TLOZ: Ocarina of Time, Spyro, etc.

Here is another example: https://twitter.com/JasperRLZ/status/1094624131012714498

I would like to use this technique in my level models and then **export them to Unity**, but I can't find a way of doing it. The best I could find is this video, but it doesn't work for me when I do it, and it does not explain much of what they are doing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VEdMQIF_sU
If anyone knows how to do this, please do tell. Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30314
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90890
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31330 https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=vertex%20colors%20export

Comment: Nevermind, I already found an actual solution: https://blenderartists.org/t/vertex-coloring-on-textured-models-to-use-in-unity/1230383/3